# Linq Recursive Sum

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have the following data strucure:

```
        List<Item> Items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item{ Id = 1, Name = "Machine" },
            new Item{ Id = 3, Id_Parent = 1,  Name = "Machine1"},
            new Item{ Id = 5, Id_Parent = 3,  Name = "Machine1-A", Number = 2, Price = 10 },
            new Item{ Id = 9, Id_Parent = 3,  Name = "Machine1-B", Number = 4, Price = 11 },
            new Item{ Id = 100,  Name = "Item" } ,
            new Item{ Id = 112,  Id_Parent = 100, Name = "Item1", Number = 5, Price = 55 }
        };
```

I want to build a query that gets the sum of all children price in its parent (items are related by Id_Parent).
For example, for Item Id = 100, I have 55, because thats the value of the its child .

For Item Id = 3 I have 21, becaue Item Id = 5 and Id = 9 all sum to that.
So far soo good.

What I am strugling to get is for Item Id = 1 I should also have the sum = 21, because Id = 3 is a child of Id = 1 and it has a sum of 21.

Here is my code:

```
        var result = from i in items
                                   join item in item on i.Id_Parent equals item.Id
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Name = prod.Nome,
                                       Sum =
                                         (from it in items
                                          where it.Id_Parent == item.Id
                                          group it by new
                                          {
                                              it.Id_Parent
                                          }
                                          into g
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Price)
                                          }
                                         ).First()
                                   };
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: I'd create a lookup on the parent id and do a recursive method to sum up the values of all the children.  Linq's not the best with recursion.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to build up an in-memory representation of your items that does not look like it was read straight out of a database? It would be nice if `Item` had an `IEnumerable<Item> Children` property and an `Item Parent` property. If you had those then the problem of writing `fold` on the data structure becomes much easier.

Comment: [You may want to consider not using underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782084/naming-conventions-in-c-sharp-underscores).  Nothing technically wrong with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a recursive function to find all the children of a parent:

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendents(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id) {
    foreach (var item in src.Where(i => i.Id_Parent == parent_id)) {
        yield return item;
        foreach (var itemd in ItemDescendents(src, item.Id))
            yield return itemd;
    }
}
```

Now you can get the price for any parent:

```
var price1 = ItemDescendants(Items, 1).Sum(i => i.Price);
```

Note if you know that the children of an item are always greater in id value than their parent, you don't need recursion:

```
var descendents = Items.OrderBy(i => i.Id).Aggregate(new List<Item>(), (ans, i) => {
    if (i.Id_Parent == 1 || ans.Select(a => a.Id).Contains(i.Id_Parent))
        ans.Add(i);
    return ans;
});
```

For those that prefer to avoid recursion, you can use an explicit stack instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendentsFlat(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id) {
    void PushRange<T>(Stack<T> s, IEnumerable<T> Ts) {
        foreach (var aT in Ts)
            s.Push(aT);
    }

    var itemStack = new Stack<Item>(src.Where(i => i.Id_Parent == parent_id));

    while (itemStack.Count > 0) {
        var item = itemStack.Pop();
        PushRange(itemStack, src.Where(i => i.Id_Parent == item.Id));
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

I included `PushRange` helper function since `Stack` doesn't have one.

Finally, here is a variation that doesn't use any stack, implicit or explicit.

```
public IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendantsFlat2(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id) {
    var children = src.Where(s => s.Id_Parent == parent_id);
    do {
        foreach (var c in children)
            yield return c;
        children = children.SelectMany(c => src.Where(i => i.Id_Parent == c.Id)).ToList();
    } while (children.Count() > 0);
}
```

You can replace the multiple traversals of the source with a `Lookup` as well:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendantsFlat3(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id) {
    var childItems = src.ToLookup(i => i.Id_Parent);

    var children = childItems[parent_id];
    do {
        foreach (var c in children)
            yield return c;
        children = children.SelectMany(c => childItems[c.Id]).ToList();
    } while (children.Count() > 0);
}
```

I optimized the above based on the comments about too much nested enumeration, which improved performance vastly, but I was also inspired to attempt to remove `SelectMany` which can be slow, and collect `IEnumerable`s as I've seen suggested elsewhere to optimize `Concat`:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendantsFlat4(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id) {
    var childItems = src.ToLookup(i => i.Id_Parent);

    var stackOfChildren = new Stack<IEnumerable<Item>>();
    stackOfChildren.Push(childItems[parent_id]);
    do
        foreach (var c in stackOfChildren.Pop()) {
            yield return c;
            stackOfChildren.Push(childItems[c.Id]);
        }
    while (stackOfChildren.Count > 0);
}
```

@AntonínLejsek's `GetDescendants` is still fastest, though it is very close now, but sometimes simpler wins out for performance.

Comment: This is a nice idea but you can do better. First, notice how you use no property of `List<Item>` when using src, so it could be `IEnumerable<Item>`.  Second, you build up the entire result set as a `List<Item>`, but you could instead `yield return` each element in turn, and that way you don't have to have the entire data structure in memory twice. Finally, the method is mis-named; these are *descendants* of the item, not the *children* of the item.

Comment: Always humbling to be schooled by @EricLippert :) BTW, how would you handle `yield return` of the recursive call? (And when will you add `yield return all` to C#?.)

Comment: Well I have not been on the C# team for over five years, so I'm unlikely to add `yield return all`, though it would be useful!  I would just do it in a loop.

Comment: Depending on depth, this solution could cause a `StackOverflowException`. (no joke intended).

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Indeed it could; and even if it did not, there's an additional O(h) time multiplier on the cost of the method where h is the height of the tallest tree in the forest. There are mechanisms for getting around this where we turn the O(h) time multiplier into O(h) additional space.

Comment: Probably best to make that an extension method with the `this` keyword.

Comment: Also the `pop` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if Id passed has no [matching records](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vk6Os4).

Comment: @EricLippert Oh do you have an example of that?  I mean I can't imagine how O(h) time is some how negated by O(h) space.  Or did you mean you can void a SOE via O(h) space?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yes, but I don't like assuming extension methods in an answer. Maybe extensions everything could include anywhere and allow local static extensions.  My actual `PushRange` is `public static void PushRange<T>(this Stack<T> s, IEnumerable<T> Ts) => Ts.ForEach(aT => s.Push(aT));`  Thanks, the `pop` error was because I was trying to re-order the code to be more DRY and posted the wrong version. I corrected it.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969963/when-not-to-use-yield-return/3970171#3970171 -- as NetMage points out in the recent edit, you can use an explicit stack to avoid the recursion.

Comment: Multiple enumeration of IEnumerable is not good, you calculate the same thing over and over again in your last two solutions.

Comment: @ErikPhilips My vision on that is explicit stack of `IEnumerator<T>` presented in [How to flatten tree via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq/31881243#31881243)

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried to create something like that based on a comment from Eric's blog post, but there is only one `IEnumerable` here, I don't think it applies.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Blame @EricLippert for that :), I started out with a `List<Item>`. In most cases, I don't think multiple enumerations are harmful (it isn't likely our source `IEnumerable` will be expensive to compute, and if it is, the caller should instantiate it) and there is no specified ordering for children so you must scan the entire (possibly remaining) `src` for children. Note that `children` is reassigned each time through the loop, so it isn't the same calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure removing the found children is worth it, but I wrote a sort function that sorted parents above children that does that to make the `Aggregate` function work without requiring any `Id` ordering.

Comment: @NetMage The comment wasn't about your answer/approach :) But once you asked, it could be applied in combination with `ToLookup` or `Where` - note the elements selector lambda. e.g. `Items.Where(e => e.Id_Parent == parentId).Expand(p => Items.Where(e => e.Id_Parent == p.Id))` gives you all children of that parent, w/o recursive iterator.

Comment: @IvanStoev Very nice - you should make that an answer!

Comment: @NetMage Regarding recusive iterators, the problem is the top level (end user) `MoveNext` leads to `h` nested `MoveNext` calls. Imagine a very deep tree like in Windows explorer with `h` >= 100

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, I saw that from what I mis-remembered as Eric's blog but was one he referenced by Wes Dyer. A comment by richard_deeming mentioned improving `Concat` by gathering the iterators and then processing them in sequence.

Comment: @NetMage There is no need to put my own answer because it basically would be a duplicate (with only applying `Sum` at the end), and your answer provided enough alternatives and solved OP issue. I'm commenting just because noticed you seem to be interested in custom extension methods (DRY) :) Happy coding!

Comment: The children is reassigned, but it uses the previous IEnumerable, you just chain the enumerations. So you append to it and calculate everything from scratch again in the next step. And you do it twice, once for foreach and once for Count(). For depth 1000 you enumerate the whole source collection cca 1000000 times. Enumerating is fast, but enumerating 1000000000 items is actually not that fast.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Do you think a `ToList` on children would be appropriate then?

Comment: @EricLippert Missed your (kind) answer! I saw where it should be `yield foreach` which I think is very nice, and apparently can have large advantages over using a loop in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to use a local function, like this:

```
int CalculatePrice(int id)
{
    int price = Items.Where(item => item.Id_Parent == id).Sum(child => CalculatePrice(child.Id));
    return price + Items.First(item => item.Id == id).Price;
}
int total = CalculatePrice(3); // 3 is just an example id
```

Another, cleaner solution instead would be to use the [Y combinator](http://blog.klipse.tech/lambda/2016/08/10/pure-y-combinator-javascript.html) to create a closure that can be called inline. Assuming you have this

```
/// <summary>
/// Implements a recursive function that takes a single parameter
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The Type of the Func parameter</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TResult">The Type of the value returned by the recursive function</typeparam>
/// <param name="f">The function that returns the recursive Func to execute</param>
/// <returns>The recursive Func with the given code</returns>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static Func<T, TResult> Y<T, TResult>(Func<Func<T, TResult>, Func<T, TResult>> f)
{
    Func<T, TResult> g = null;
    g = f(a => g(a));
    return g;
}
```

Then you can just get your result like so:

```
int total = Y<int, int>(x => y =>
{
    int price = Items.Where(item => item.Id_Parent == y).Sum(child => x(child.Id));
    return price + Items.First(item => item.Id == y).Price;
})(3);
```

What's nice about this is that it allows you to quickly declare and call a recursive function in a functional-fashion, which is especially handy in situations like this one, where you only need "throwaway" functions that you'll use just once. Also, since this function is quite small, using the Y combinator further reduces the boilerplate of having to declare a local function and call it on another line.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers who may experience a `StackOverflowException`, the alternative I use is in the following example:  ([dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6VpaUg))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item{ Id = 1, Name = "Machine" },
            new Item{ Id = 3, Id_Parent = 1,  Name = "Machine1"},
            new Item{ Id = 5, Id_Parent = 3,  Name = "Machine1-A", Number = 2, Price = 10 },
            new Item{ Id = 9, Id_Parent = 3,  Name = "Machine1-B", Number = 4, Price = 11 },
            new Item{ Id = 100,  Name = "Item" } ,
            new Item{ Id = 112,  Id_Parent = 100, Name = "Item1", Number = 5, Price = 55 }
        };
        
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} $" + GetSum(items, item.Id).ToString(), item.Name, item.Id);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static int GetSum(IEnumerable<Item> items, int id)
    {
        // add all matching items
        var itemsToSum = items.Where(i => i.Id == id).ToList();
        var oldCount = 0;
        var currentCount = itemsToSum.Count();
        // it nothing was added we skip the while
        while (currentCount != oldCount)
        {
            oldCount = currentCount;
            // find all matching items except the ones already in the list
            var matchedItems = items
                .Join(itemsToSum, item => item.Id_Parent, sum => sum.Id, (item, sum) => item)
                .Except(itemsToSum)
                .ToList();
            itemsToSum.AddRange(matchedItems);
            currentCount = itemsToSum.Count;
        }
        
        return itemsToSum.Sum(i => i.Price);
    }
    
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Id_Parent { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
    }
}
```

Result:

> Machine 1 $21
>
> Machine1 3 $21
>
> Machine1-A 5 $10
>
> Machine1-B 9 $11
>
> Item 100 $55
>
> Item1 112 $55

Basically we create a list with the initial items matching the id passed.  If the id doesn't match we have no items and we skip the while loop.  If we do have items, then we join to find all items that have a parent id of the items we currently have.  From that list we then exclude the ones already in the list.  Then append what we've found.  Eventually there are no more items in the list that have matching parent id's.

Comment: That seems a bit excessive / expensive.

Comment: As i mentioned, this is the alternative if you get a stack overflow.

Comment: I added an explicit stack version that can't cause stack overflow, and does a lot less processing than a `Join` / `Except` for every generation.

Comment: @NetMage Join for every depth step is expensive, but src.Where for every Item output can be even worse.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek In my recursive function, `Where` returns all children for a parent, it is not done per child.

Comment: @NetMage I thought You were talking about the explicit stack version.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many solutions that it is worth to make a benchmark. I added my solution to the mix too, it is the last function. Some functions include the root node and some not, but apart from this they return the same result. I tested wide tree with 2 children per parent and narrow tree with just one children per parent (depth is equal to number of items). And the results are:

```
---------- Wide 100000 3 ----------
ItemDescendents: 9592ms
ItemDescendentsFlat: 9544ms
ItemDescendentsFlat2: 45826ms
ItemDescendentsFlat3: 30ms
ItemDescendentsFlat4: 11ms
CalculatePrice: 23849ms
Y: 24265ms
GetSum: 62ms
GetDescendants: 19ms

---------- Narrow 3000 3 ----------
ItemDescendents: 100ms
ItemDescendentsFlat: 24ms
ItemDescendentsFlat2: 75948ms
ItemDescendentsFlat3: 1004ms
ItemDescendentsFlat4: 1ms
CalculatePrice: 69ms
Y: 69ms
GetSum: 915ms
GetDescendants: 0ms
```

While premature optimalization is bad, it is important to know what the asymptotic behaviour is. Asymptotic behaviour determines if the algorithm would scale or would die.

And the code follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Test
        {
            public static IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendents(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id)
            {
                foreach (var item in src.Where(i => i.Id_Parent == parent_id))
                {
                    yield return item;
                    foreach (var itemd in ItemDescendents(src, item.Id))
                        yield return itemd;
                }
            }

            public static IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendentsFlat(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id)
            {
                void PushRange<T>(Stack<T> s, IEnumerable<T> Ts)
                {
                    foreach (var aT in Ts)
                        s.Push(aT);
                }

                var itemStack = new Stack<Item>(src.Where(i => i.Id_Parent == parent_id));

                while (itemStack.Count > 0)
                {
                    var item = itemStack.Pop();
                    PushRange(itemStack, src.Where(i => i.Id_Parent == item.Id));
                    yield return item;
                };
            }

            public IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendantsFlat2(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id)
            {
                var children = src.Where(s => s.Id_Parent == parent_id);
                do
                {
                    foreach (var c in children)
                        yield return c;
                    children = children.SelectMany(c => src.Where(i => i.Id_Parent == c.Id));
                } while (children.Count() > 0);
            }

            public IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendantsFlat3(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id)
            {
                var childItems = src.ToLookup(i => i.Id_Parent);

                var children = childItems[parent_id];
                do
                {
                    foreach (var c in children)
                        yield return c;
                    children = children.SelectMany(c => childItems[c.Id]);
                } while (children.Count() > 0);
            }

            public IEnumerable<Item> ItemDescendantsFlat4(IEnumerable<Item> src, int parent_id)
            {
                var childItems = src.ToLookup(i => i.Id_Parent);

                var stackOfChildren = new Stack<IEnumerable<Item>>();
                stackOfChildren.Push(childItems[parent_id]);
                do
                    foreach (var c in stackOfChildren.Pop())
                    {
                        yield return c;
                        stackOfChildren.Push(childItems[c.Id]);
                    }
                while (stackOfChildren.Count > 0);
            }

            public static int GetSum(IEnumerable<Item> items, int id)
            {
                // add all matching items
                var itemsToSum = items.Where(i => i.Id == id).ToList();
                var oldCount = 0;
                var currentCount = itemsToSum.Count();
                // it nothing was added we skip the while
                while (currentCount != oldCount)
                {
                    oldCount = currentCount;
                    // find all matching items except the ones already in the list
                    var matchedItems = items
                        .Join(itemsToSum, item => item.Id_Parent, sum => sum.Id, (item, sum) => item)
                        .Except(itemsToSum)
                        .ToList();
                    itemsToSum.AddRange(matchedItems);
                    currentCount = itemsToSum.Count;
                }

                return itemsToSum.Sum(i => i.Price);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Implements a recursive function that takes a single parameter
            /// </summary>
            /// <typeparam name="T">The Type of the Func parameter</typeparam>
            /// <typeparam name="TResult">The Type of the value returned by the recursive function</typeparam>
            /// <param name="f">The function that returns the recursive Func to execute</param>
            /// <returns>The recursive Func with the given code</returns>
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            public static Func<T, TResult> Y<T, TResult>(Func<Func<T, TResult>, Func<T, TResult>> f)
            {
                Func<T, TResult> g = null;
                g = f(a => g(a));
                return g;
            }


            public IEnumerable<Item> GetDescendants(IEnumerable<Item> items, int key)
            {
                var lookup = items.ToLookup(i => i.Id_Parent);
                Stack<Item> st = new Stack<Item>(lookup[key]);

                while (st.Count > 0)
                {
                    var item = st.Pop();
                    yield return item;
                    foreach (var i in lookup[item.Id])
                    {
                        st.Push(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            public class Item
            {
                public int Id;
                public int Price;
                public int Id_Parent;
            }

            protected Item[] getItems(int count, bool wide)
            {
                Item[] Items = new Item[count];
                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                {
                    Item ix = new Item()
                    {
                        Id = i,
                        Id_Parent = wide ? i / 2 : i - 1,
                        Price = i % 17
                    };
                    Items[i] = ix;
                }
                return Items;
            }

            public void test()
            {
                Item[] items = null;

                int CalculatePrice(int id)
                {
                    int price = items.Where(item => item.Id_Parent == id).Sum(child => CalculatePrice(child.Id));
                    return price + items.First(item => item.Id == id).Price;
                }

                var functions = new List<(Func<Item[], int, int>, string)>() {
                ((it, key) => ItemDescendents(it, key).Sum(i => i.Price), "ItemDescendents"),
                ((it, key) => ItemDescendentsFlat(it, key).Sum(i => i.Price), "ItemDescendentsFlat"),
                ((it, key) => ItemDescendantsFlat2(it, key).Sum(i => i.Price), "ItemDescendentsFlat2"),
                ((it, key) => ItemDescendantsFlat3(it, key).Sum(i => i.Price), "ItemDescendentsFlat3"),
                ((it, key) => ItemDescendantsFlat4(it, key).Sum(i => i.Price), "ItemDescendentsFlat4"),
                ((it, key) => CalculatePrice(key), "CalculatePrice"),
                ((it, key) => Y<int, int>(x => y =>
                {
                    int price = it.Where(item => item.Id_Parent == y).Sum(child => x(child.Id));
                    return price + it.First(item => item.Id == y).Price;
                })(key), "Y"),
                ((it, key) => GetSum(it, key), "GetSum"),
                ((it, key) => GetDescendants(it, key).Sum(i => i.Price), "GetDescendants" )                 
                };

                System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch st = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

                var testSetup = new[]
                {
                    new { Count = 10, Wide = true, Key=3}, //warmup
                    new { Count = 100000, Wide = true, Key=3},
                    new { Count = 3000, Wide = false, Key=3}
                };

                List<int> sums = new List<int>();
                foreach (var setup in testSetup)
                {
                    items = getItems(setup.Count, setup.Wide);
                    Console.WriteLine("---------- " + (setup.Wide ? "Wide" : "Narrow")
                        + " " + setup.Count + " " + setup.Key + " ----------");
                    foreach (var func in functions)
                    {
                        st.Restart();
                        sums.Add(func.Item1(items, setup.Key));
                        st.Stop();
                        Console.WriteLine(func.Item2 + ": " + st.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("checks: " + string.Join(", ", sums));
                    sums.Clear();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("---------- END ----------");

            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.test();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Your code has `GetSum` before `Y` but your output is the other way around. The checks for `GetSum` and `Y` don't seem to match the others either?

Comment: @NetMage You are right, I forgot to swap them in the code. CalculatePrice and Y belong together, they are almost the same. The checks differ because some algorithms include the root node and some not, I already addressed this in the answer.

Comment: @NetMage btw I like your ItemDescendentsFlat4. But do not fall into trap of excessive optimalization. It does not really matter if it is 30% faster here and 10% slower there (it would change in the future anyway). What matters, and I wanted to show, is, that bad asymptotic behaviour can make your solution easily 1000x slower. That is thing you should watch because that does matter.

Comment: Without any particulars on the data, this is all premature optimization, regardless of behavior. Sometimes smarter solutions are slower because they have too much overhead for simpler problems.