# C# - Naming conventions for internal members

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, member, internal

What are the naming conventions for `internal` members in C#?

For example, default access modifier for WPF controls is internal - how should I name them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All non-public members should be `lowerCamelCase`.

Comment: Don't you mean all 'private', @SLaks? 'internal' is not public but not private and PascalCase is usually used.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: I don't think so, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

you don't usually name WPF controls. Unless you intend to use things such as UIA on them.

That being said, take a look at the [Official C# Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)

Edit: Even if you plan to use UIA on your application, you should avoid naming controls unless needed. This encourages good practices (MVVM, separation of UI and logic) and prevents lazy / unexperienced developers from resorting to winforms-like code behind practices.

UIA may also rely on properties such as `AutomationProperties.AutomationId`, therefore completely removing the need to give a name to WPF controls, unless of course you will use them as storyboard targets or you need some `ElementName` binding.

Comment: What is UIA? I googled that it means UI Automation, but I have heard about it for the first time.

Comment: I name a WPF control, when I want to do something with it programmatically in runtime - for example disable some controls when something happens, or add text to `TextBox`, etc. Is it bad to do it?

Comment: @PeterSivák yes it's bad to to that. if you need to programatically disable a control, then you **bind** it's `IsEnabled` property to some bool property in the ViewModel and manipulate that.

Comment: I have read [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) you told me, but there was mentioned nothing about `internal` members :) . By the way, why there is an option to name WPF control, when it is bad?

Comment: @PeterSivák as advised by @SLaks, you should use `lowerCamelCase`. Still, I insist that you should not name WPF controls.

Comment: @PeterSivák There's also an option to use `goto` in C#. There's also an option not to create any classes and manipulate all your data as a `Dictionary<string,string>` within an application. The fact that something is possible doesn't mean it's good. Manipulating UI elements in procedural code is not needed nor desired in WPF. Read up on MVVM.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can set a UI Automation Name without setting a WPF Name. You can set the former with the `AutomationProperties.Name` attached property and the latter with the `FrameworkElement.Name` dependency property. For some controls, the UIA Name defaults to using the `FrameworkElement.Name`, if it is specified.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes non-public members can be _lowerCamelCase.

Here is a link
[Naming convention - underscore in C++ and C# variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136594/naming-convention-underscore-in-c-c-variables)