# How do I keep track of time before executing any function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this service which calls Notification() function every second. What this function does is it checks the time difference between `lastupdated` and `DateTime.UtcNow` and check if the `Countdiff` is greater than 1

If the above conditions is true then it checks if the `AppGuid` is already in the DB if it's not it inserts it and calls `DoAction()` function which sends a notification. Everything works fine till here.

The problem starts when the `AppGuid` is already in DB.

What I need is if `AppGuid` is already in DB then send notification every 15 Min, here I'm struggling with keeping track last time I send notification, I tried to compare last `timestamp` when it got updated and tried to compare the difference but it keeps sending notifications resulting spamming the pipeline.

I tried to keep elasped time with stopwatch class but the problem it waits for 15 min when app starts initially to send anything.

How do I send notification only once every 15 min?

```
public class DataGetService : DelegatingHandler, IHostedService
{
    private Timer _timer;
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        _timer = new Timer(Heartbeat, null, 1000, 1000);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Timer does not have a stop. 
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Heartbeat(object state)
    {
        _ = Notifications(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
    }

    public async Task Notifications(TimeSpan period)
    {
        // Result array have: LastUpdated, CountDiff, AppGuid, AppName, Timestamp
        foreach (var d in result)
        {
            var x = _DBcontext.TestEvents.FirstOrDefault(o => o.AppGuid == (Guid)d.AppGuid);

            if (DateTime.UtcNow - d.LastUpdated <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) && d.CountDiff > 1)
            {
                if (x == null)
                {
                    DoAction();
                    _DBcontext.TestEvents.Add(new TestEvents
                    {
                        AppGuid = (Guid)d.AppGuid,
                        AppName = d.AppName,
                        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
                    });
                }
                else
                {   //This is useful if app have crashed or was not able to update in db, it will update the current timestamp. 
                    if (DateTime.UtcNow - x.Timestamp >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
                    {
                        x.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (stopwatch.Elapsed <= period)
                            return;

                        DoAction();
                        x.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();

        stopwatch.Restart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh i see, never mind

Comment: I would use a System.Timers.Timer.... AutoReset = false.  and when I switch from 1 second to 15 minutes I would play aroung with the Interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it the same way I would lock a user out for 15 minutes if they tried their password too many times: rather than trying to use a date field that tracks when a record was last updated, have a dedicated field for when the next event should be raised. At the time you send the first notification, set it to a future date and only send a new notification when the date falls into the past (whereupon you set the date future again)

By using a "last updated" field you risk another notification if something else about the record changes. If you feel that it's not relevant to put the date in the table concerned, consider having a table just for notification event dates; all it needs is a GUID and a date, and then it can function for any object ID in any table in the database (if the GUIDs are unique) - "no sending information about entity with GUID x until time y" is an easy thing to code for in that case and the eventing system doesnt need to know anything about the entity it is reporting on. You can make the subsystems naively raise events every second if they want to, but the sending of notifications can only happen every X minutes, so all the interim notifications are quenched. This simplifies the system raising the messages too; it can just raise them and not care for the logic of whether they should actually be notified or not

Answer (score 1):

For future answer seekers:

I have added `futureTime` variable which adds 15 min to the Timestamp from DB.

The interesting thing was when I compare with `if(DateTime.UtcNow == futureTime)` the condition never became true, reason what I have understood is I call this function every second during the execution somehow system was skipping the time resulting `false` condition.

To overcome this I took the difference `(DateTime.UtcNow - futureTime)` and also consider the tolerance of seconds.

```
if (DateTime.UtcNow - d.LastUpdated <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) && d.CountDiff > 1)
{
    if (x == null)
    {
        DoAction();
        _DBcontext.TestEvents.Add(new TestEvents
        {
            AppGuid = (Guid)item.AppGuid,
            AppName = item.AppName,
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
        });
    }
    //This is useful if app have crashed or was not able to update in db, it will update the current timestamp. 
    else if (DateTime.UtcNow - x.Timestamp >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
    {
        x.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    else
    {
        //This will set the notification date in future 
        DateTime dbtimestamp = x.Timestamp;
        DateTime futureTime = dbtimestamp.AddMinutes(15);

        if (((DateTime.UtcNow - futureTime) - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Duration() < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        {
            DoAction();
            x.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
}
```