# Erasing vector elements while in a range-based loop vs. standard loop

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

If I erase all 5 elements of a vector during first iteration of a standard for loop

```
std::vector<int> test {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for(int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++)
{
    if(test[i] == 1) test.erase(test.begin(), test.end());
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

it will iterate only once and the std::cout output will be '0'.

However if I do the same thing using a range-based loop, it will iterate 5 times, despite all elements of vector being erased.

```
int i = 0;
for (auto &a: test)
{
    if (a==1) test.erase(test.begin(), test.end());
    std::cout << i << " ";
    i++;
}
```

And the std::cout output will be '0 1 2 3 4'.

Where does such different behaviour come from, when using those two types of loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **first** case, for each iteration `std::vector::size` function is being called. Thus, if you delete all the elements in the first iteration, `std::vector::size` function which is called before the start of second iteration will return 0. Therefore, second iteration won't happen because the condition `i < test.size()` is not satisfied.

In the **second** case, range-based for loop uses iterators instead of `std::vector::size` function. When you call `std::vector::erase` you invalidate all the iterators including the `end()` iterator. Therefore, second case is actually UB (Undefined Behavior) and you should **never** rely on that.

From the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

> `std::vector::erase`
>
> ... Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the
>   erase, including the end() iterator.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the first case it seemed logical to me that the iteration ends once size of vector is equal to 0 but I struggled to understand why in the second case it doesn't end. The fact that it's undefined behavior explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

From the standard, [[stmt.ranged]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.ranged#1)

> The range-based for statement
>
> for ( ***init-statement*** *opt* ***for-range-declaration*** : ***for-range-initializer*** ) ***statement***
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>   init-statement opt     
>   auto &&range = for-range-initializer ;
>   auto begin = begin-expr ;
>   auto end = end-expr ;
>   for ( ; begin != end; ++begin ) {
>       for-range-declaration = * begin ;
>       statement
>   }
> }
> ```

Note that the begin and end iterators are initialized before the loop itself begins. If you perform erasing in the loop which making the iterators invalid then the code leads to UB.

On the other hand, the 1st code snippet checks `test.size()` every iteration. When the elements get erased and the `size()` beomes `0` the loop ends immediately.

Comment: So that's undefined behaviour. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you using underscores in names? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136594/naming-convention-underscore-in-c-and-c-sharp-variables/20496955

Comment: @northerner It's not me, I got it from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation), and I think it's written at the aspect of the language (or compiler). Anyway, I changed the pseudocode to the one got from the standard.