# CLS compat Public properties naming validation routine

Tags: c#, member, reflection.emit, cls-compliant

Im working on a system that allows one to define data types (types that have only public properties) on the fly (undercovers using reflection.emit), i want my new types to also be CLS compliant, what would a validator that validates member names need to take into account in order to be CLS compliant, im only interested in what a function would validate in order to determine if the entered name is ok..

something like

```
bool IsValidMemberName(string name)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look here for the rules: [Why is this name with an underscore not CLS Compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195030/why-is-this-name-not-cls-compliant). Now you simply need to build a regex that checks for those rules. Shouldn't be too hard.