# VS 2010 Name is not CLS-compliant error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have tried several ways to find a solution to this problem and have come up blank. Hence the post. I am using visual studio 2010 and building an application using VB and when I run(debug) I get the following errors.

**A field in the dataset ‘DataSet1’ has the name ‘Invoice address’. Field names must be CLS-compliant identifiers.**

There are many of these pointing to the dataset and quite frankly, I am not sure how go about solving it. I have used: `<Assembly: CLSCompliant(False)>` in AssemblyInfo.vb but still the errors come. I read somewhere that this line is to be put in a file AssemblyInfo.cs. I do not have one of those. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something like "Invoice_address", without a space?

Comment: @Pointy Quite frankly, I would just rather remove CLS altogether. Thanks

Comment: @Pointy out of interest, is that done at database level or xml file?

Comment: You might try "[Invoice address]" - this is the way to handle field names with spaces or reserved names in T-SQL; not sure if it would work from your code though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CLSCompliant` does not work in this case. The problem is that the field name `Invoice address` contains a space and so the identifier is not CLS compliant ([Why is this name with an underscore not CLS Compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195030/why-is-this-name-not-cls-compliant)).

The context is not stated in the question, but this error often occurs in RDK reports.

The Report Designer solves the problem by renaming fields

```
<Field name="non_CLS_Compliant_Name">
 <DataField>non CLS Compliant Name</DataField>
 </Field>
```

In code you should replace all non compliant characters in names with underscore (_) and add ID at the beginning to solve problems with the first character

```
Dim RgxGlobal As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Nl}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Cf}]")
Dim RgxStart As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\A[^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Nl}]")
Dim NewFieldName As String = RgxGlobal.Replace(ColName, "_")
If RgxStart.IsMatch(NewFieldName) Then NewFieldName = "ID" & NewFieldName
```

Comment: But the real question is why the VS Designer is auto-generating code that has bugs.  Isn't that pathetic?