# CLS Compliant when running report

Tags: c#, report

I've created a report, and when i'm trying to run the whole app it giving an error that says:

> Error 1   A field in the dataset ‘DataSet1’ has the name ‘Student
>   Number’. Field names must be CLS-compliant identifiers.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195030/why-is-this-name-with-an-underscore-not-cls-compliant . I guess you have to remove the empty space in "Student Number"

Answer (score 0):

Changing name of my field according to [CLS-Compilance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.100).aspx) resolved issue for me.